# btrfs snapshot management

Tags: backup, btrfs

1) Is there a gui or curses tool that allows you to view/manage btrfs subvols/snapshots?

2) Is there a utility or already made script that would automatically create and delete snapshots daily/weekly? I'm aware that I could probably use a simple sh via cron but is there anything more elaborate that already exists?

Comment: Not answer but related: http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/SystemRollbackWithBtrfs

Comment: I've started a project called [snazzer](https://github.com/csirac2/snazzer), which offers btrfs snapshotting, pruning and transport via ssh or local filesystems. It's not quite ready for release but I would love to hear feedback if anybody has time to review it at this early stage. CLI-only at this point.

Answer (score 6):

1) I have not seen any GUI or curses tool.

2) There are a couple of existing scripts out there.  I haven't tried them, but they look interesting:

SnapBtr:  https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/SnapBtr

btrfs-snap: http://blog.patshead.com/2010/11/tweak-btrfs-snap-for-more-frequent-snapshots.html

A related btrfs development is the announcement that Natty (11.04) will feature automatic btrfs rollback for packages.  I.e., for btrfs installations it will automatically snapshot before any apt install/upgrade/remove operation:
http://mvogt.wordpress.com/2011/03/10/apt-btrfs-snapshot/

Answer (score 2):

I found [timeshift](https://linuxreviews.org/Btrfs#btrfs_Tips_and_Tricks) to work far better than snapper-GUI, except while in SUSE, where snapper rocks! https://github.com/teejee2008/timeshift

Answer (score 1):

[snapper](http://snapper.io/) is a command-line tool designed to manage btrfs snapshots, and can be used with [snapper-gui](https://github.com/ricardomv/snapper-gui).

`snapper` is available for ubuntu. It can be configured to take time-based snapshots, reboot snapshots and even take snapshots every time `apt` is called. In 18.04, snapshot triggered by boot or `apt` are enable by default (after configuring snapshots for `/`.

If you plan to use snapper (or any other snapshot tool), I would recommend you to make a separate volume (or partition) for:

- `/tmp` : snapshots will be a pure waste of space.
- `/var/log` : so you can preserve your logs even after a restoration.

This tool : [grub-btrfs](https://github.com/Antynea/grub-btrfs), can be used to generate bootable grub entries for your snapshots.

Answer (score 0):

There's a generic GUI tool called [btrfs-gui](http://carfax.org.uk/btrfs-gui) but it's in early stages of development as of this writing and can only list, but not create/modify snapshots.

Comment: The project seems to be abandoned now, no changes in over 4 years.

Answer (score 0):

Some tools are listed in the question ["btrfs-enabled backup solution"](https://serverfault.com/questions/356397).

The btrfs wiki page "[Use Cases](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/UseCases#How_can_I_use_btrfs_for_backups.2Ftime-machine.3F)" lists some tools: SnapBtr, Snapper, btrfs-time-machine, UrBackup.

There's a proposal for a built-in tool called autosnap, which "could configure btrfs to take regular or event based snapshots and further manage the snapshots automatically". However, as October 2013, it is not available yet.